# IFrame not loading new page with changing src value

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

I am using `IFrame` to load pages from my main page. Some times first 2-3 pages load normally when I specify source on click of a link using:

```
var frame = $('#mainFrame')[0];
frame.src='/directory/example.aspx';
```

I have also tried using jQuery attribute:

```
$('#mainFrame').attr('src','/directory/example.aspx');
```

I have tested in  `Firebug` the `src` attribute is changed, but when I check following:

```
frame.content.document.location.href
```

it show a different location than that specified using `src` tag.

Please suggest some remedy as this issue is delaying all of my work :(

Answer (score 0):

I would create a javascript function that sets an innerHTML property of a div based on an XMLHTTPRequest AJAX style.  Being from IE 5 and Netscape 4.7 days I still have bad memories of Iframes and avoid them at all costs although I hear the issues are now fixed..

Answer (score 0):

Folks there I had to struggle with this again today. It seems two things (leading to the same effect) were causing `IFrame` to missbehave.

1) We are using Telerik ASP.Net AJAX controls. My colleagues were calling a function in main page of application to move it to next or previous pages like:

```
top.moveNext();
return false;
```

or

```
top.movePrevious();
return false;
```

but they were calling these in `RADButton`'s `OnClientClicked` event handler. I changed it to be called in `OnClientClicking` handler and canceled the event like:

```
function onNextClicking(s,a){
    a.set_cancel(true);//stops event from propogating
    top.moveNext();
}
```

This made it to behave correctly with pages having `RADButton`s.

2) On some pages we were using simple `button` elements. There too they were returning `false` after calling methods from `top` window. We have changed those buttons to `RADButtons` and are handling steps in `OnClientClicking` handlers. Though it seems strange that a function inside a page already loaded in the `IFrame` is causing it to stop loading new URL if it returns false.